# Invalid field in source data: 0 TCP_Message

Tags: deserialization, protobuf-net

I'm using ProtoBuf-Net for serialize and deserialize TCP_Messages.

I've tried all the suggestions I've found here, so I really don't know where the mistake is.

The serialize is made server side, and the deserialize is made on an application client-side.

Serialize code:

```
        public void MssGetCardPersonalInfo(out RCPersonalInfoRecord ssPersonalInfoObject, out bool ssResult) {
        ssPersonalInfoObject = new RCPersonalInfoRecord(null);

        TCP_Message msg = new TCP_Message(MessageTypes.GetCardPersonalInfo);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, msg);
        _tcp_Client.Send(ms.ToArray());
        _waitToReadCard.Start();
        _stopWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

And the deserialize:

```
       private void tpcServer_OnDataReceived(Object sender, byte[] data, TCPServer.StateObject clientState)
    {
        TCP_Message message = new TCP_Message();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);

        try
        {

            //ms.ToArray();
            //ms.GetBuffer();
            //ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            message = Serializer.Deserialize<TCP_Message>(ms);
        } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(_logSource, "Error deserializing: " + ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error, 103);
            }
```

As you can see, I've tried a bunch of different approache, now comented.

I have also tried to deserialize using the DeserializeWithLengthPrefix but it didn't work either.

I'm a bit noob on this, so if you could help me I would really appreciate it.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at here is: *is the data you receive the data you send*. Until you can answer "yes" to that, *all other questions are moot*. It is *very* easy to confuse network code and end up reading partial frames, etc. As a crude debugger test:

```
Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length));
```

should work. If the two base-64 strings are not identical, then you aren't working with the same data. This can be because of a range of reasons, including packet splitting and combining. You need to keep in mind that in a stream, **what you send is not what you get** - at least, not down to the *fragment* level. You might "send" data in the way of:

- one bundle of 20 bytes
- one bundle of 10 bytes

but at the receiving end, it would be entirely legitimate to read:

- 1 byte
- 22 bytes
- 7 bytes

All that TCP guarantees is the *order* and *accuracy* of the bytes. It says *nothing* about their breakdown in terms of chunks. When writing network code, there are basically 2 approaches:

- have one thread that synchronously reads from a stream and local buffer (doesn't scale well)
- async code (very scalable), but accept that you're going to have to do a lot of "do I have a complete frame? if not, append to an input buffer; if so, process any available frame data (could be multiple), then shuffle any incomplete data to the start of the buffer"